Draw dashed rectangle with PixiJS
Is it possible to draw a rectangle with a dashed line?
My code looks like:
import {Application, Graphics} from 'pixi.js';

(async () => {
    const app = new Application();
    await app.init({width: 300, height: 300});
    document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);
    
    const c = 'white';
    const x = 0;
    const y = 0;
    const w = 100;
    const h = 100;

    const graphics = new Graphics();
    graphics.rect(x, y, w, h);
    graphics.fill(c);
    graphics.stroke({ width: 1, color: 217854 });

    app.stage.addChild(graphics);    
})();

And it draws next scene:

